# How do I put an attribute as a variable in a python function?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, attributeerror

I have this function:

```py
def webdriver_wait(browser, delay, tag_name, tag, succesful_message, fail_message):
    try:
        wait_by_var = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.tag_name, tag)))
        print(succesful_message)
        return wait_by_var
    except TimeoutException:
        print(fail_message)
```

My problem comes when I execute the function. Due to the function variable `tag_name`, I get the following error:

```py
AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'tag_name'
```

I want the attribute from `By.` to be as a variable in my function, so that when I call the function `webdriver_wait()` I can choose either a `TAG_NAME`,`ÌD`,`XPATH`,`CSS_SELECTOR` etc. The rest of the variables in the function i.e. `browser`, `delay`, `tag` etc all work.

How do I create a function where I can put an attribute of `By.` as a function variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `getattr()` function to get an arbitrary attribute of a function by its name.

```
getattr(By, tag_name)
```